# Python list element elimination: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a set of data and I want to set some the elements whose values are too close to each other to 0. So let's say I have a threshold `T=1`. If `list[i+1] - list[i] < T*2`, it will set the `list[i]` element to 0. I've written some code as below:

```
a = [9, 39, 46, 76, 84, 114, 122, 150, 151, 152, 155, 198, 210]
T=1

def sort (item):
    for i in range(len(item)):
        if item[i] - item[i+1] < 2*T:
            item[i+1] == 0
    return item

print (sort(a))
```

However when I run this code, it gives me an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

My desired output is:

```
a = [9, 39, 46, 76, 84, 114, 122, 0, 0, 0, 155, 198, 210]
```

As you can see above, it sets 150,151,152 to 0. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, pls let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: You are indexing `item[i + 1]` when `i == len(item) - 1`, which gives you `item[len(item))]`, which will *always be an `IndexError`.

Comment: What's the point of setting the threshold as `T=1`, but checking for `2*T`? Why don't you set the treshold as `T=2`?

Comment: @cezar Oh becos this code is extracted from a larger set of codes so that T is also applied in somewhere else.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea I know this error happens in the last element. But would you pls let me know how to re-write the code and solve it? Thx!

Comment: What is the expected output? Should 150, 151 and 152 all be removed? Or maybe you want to keep 150, but remove only 151, consequently 152 can be kept.

Comment: @cezar pls see my edit above about desired output thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [9, 9, 46, 76, 84, 114, 122, 150, 151, 152, 155, 198, 199]
T=1

def make_zero(arr, T):
    index_values = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if i == 0:
            if abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]) < 2*T:
                index_values.append(i)
        elif i == len(arr):
            if abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]) < 2*T:
                index_values.append(i)
        elif abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]) < 2*T:
            index_values.append(i)
        elif abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]) < 2*T:
            index_values.append(i)
    for j in index_values:
        arr[j] = 0
    return arr

output = make_zero(a,T)
print output
```

Comment: You can just do `range(len(arry))` instead of `range(0, len(arr))`. I like the idea with the `index_values`.  It saves the intermediate step I'm making with calculating the distances.

Answer (score 0):

Now based on your updates I have come to a solution with some naive approach:

```
def set_neighbours_to_zero(input, threshold=1):
    # calculate the distance between the list items
    distance = {(input[i], input[i+1]): input[i+1] - input[i]
        for i in range(len(input) - 1) if i < len(input) - 1}
    # get all too close neighbours
    nullable = set()
    for k,v in distance.items():
        if v < 2 * threshold:
            nullable.update(k)
    # in the last step set the close neighbours to zero
    for n in nullable:
        index = input.index(n)
        input[index] = 0
    # return the modified list
    return input
```

If you run the function, it should return this:

```
a = [9, 39, 46, 76, 84, 114, 122, 150, 151, 152, 155, 198, 210]
print(set_neighbours_to_zero(a))
>>> [9, 39, 46, 76, 84, 114, 122, 0, 0, 0, 155, 198, 210]
```

My approach is to get the distance between all adjacent numbers in the list. Later we can set to zero all neigbhours with distance lower than the threshold.
This approach assumes the input list is always sorted in ascending order and its elements are integers.

It looks a little bit clumsy, but I hope you can improve it.

EDIT:

this part can be shortened:

```
# calculate the distance between the list items
distance = {(input[i], input[i+1]): input[i+1] - input[i]
   for i in range(len(input) - 2)}
```

We want to get the distance between a number and its consecutive neihgbour. Since the very last number in the list doesn't have a consecutive neighbour we can iterate from the first to the second to last number.
This is a dictionary comprehension and returns tupples as keys with the distance as value. Example:

```
{
    (9, 39): 30,
    (39, 46): 7,
    ...
}
```